# How do I check out only top level files from git?

Tags: git, sparse-checkout

I am trying to check out a specific file (.gitignore) committed to my git branch, and no other files.

I am able to use

`git checkout origin/master "build/system/.gitignore"`,

but when I use

`git checkout origin/master ".gitignore"`

this doesn't work.
(I get the error "error: pathspec '.gitignore' did not match any file(s) known to git.)

I have a sparse checkout of git where currently only certain directories are included in my checkout. I would like to include certain files as well.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: What do you mean by "check out a specific file"?

Comment: Move that file from the repository to my working directory and have it managed by git (but don't do so for other files also in the repository)

Comment: Is it not managed by git already?

Comment: It is managed by git, but does not appear in my working directory. I would like it to appear in my working directory without getting all other files managed by git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently git sparse-checkout doesn't work properly with files, but there seems to be a work around:

Add the file under .git/info/sparse-checkout (Add /.gitignore)

Perform a git operation, such as changing branches.

.gitignore will then populate in your local repository.